# VBA to scrape the value from a hidden field

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping, scrape

I'm new to scraping HTML and have been trying for several days now to scrape the value from a hidden field using the class name and the id, but I still can't get the value.

I'm trying to get the value (4) from the following HTML;

```html
<input id="collectionQuantity" type="hidden" value="4">
```

This is taken from larger extract below;

```html
<div class="lg-24 md-12 cols">
     
 <input id="selectedBranchCode" type="hidden" value="OT4">
 <input id="selectedBranchName" type="hidden" value="Ashton-under-Lyne">
 <input id="collectionQuantity" type="hidden" value="4">
      
  <button id="add_for_collection_button_3730P" title="Click here to add this item to your basket for collection" class="btn btn--lg btn--col fill " data-content="add-to-basket">Click &amp; Collect</button>
  <p id="branch_collection_3730P">4 in stock in <strong>Ashton-under-Lyne</strong> <a href="https://www.screwfix.com/jsp/cpc/cpcCheckStock.jsp?product_id=3730P" id="click_and_collect_3730P" class="_btn--link">Change store</a></p>
             
    </div>
```

I've tried sooooo many ways of getting the value.
The one's I think I've got closest with are;

```html
sh01.Cells(r, 5) = HTML.getElementsByClassName("lg-24 md-12 cols")(3).innertext                                  'product stock
sh01.Cells(r, 5) = HTML.getElementsByTagName("p")(7).innertext                                                   'product stock
sh01.Cells(r, 5) = HTML.getElementById("branch_collection_" & z_sh01.Cells(y, 2)).innertext                      'product stock
sh01.Cells(r, 5) = HTML.getElementsByClassName("lg-24 md-12 cols")(3).getElementById("collectionQuantity").Value 'product stock
sh01.Cells(r, 5) = HTML.querySelector("# branch_collection_" & z_sh01.Cells(y, 2)).innertext                     'product stock
sh01.Cells(r, 5) = HTML.getElementById("collectionQuantity").innertext                                           'product stock
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Ian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
HTML.querySelector("#collectionQuantity").Value
```

Or

```
HTML.getElementById("collectionQuantity").getAttribute("value")
```

Or even

```
HTML.getElementById("collectionQuantity").Value
```

You are after the value of the `value` attribute of the target element rather than the `.innerText` . The above shows 3 ways to do that.

---

So, I had to set a local store and then add a different navigate first to ensure the local store was set before going to the page of interest, otherwise the store is left blank and thus the .value of the element in question is also blank

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "https://www.screwfix.com/jsp/tradeCounter/tradeCounterDetailsPage.jsp?id=460"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        .document.querySelector("input.btn").Click

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        .Navigate2 "https://www.screwfix.com/p/hd907-9q-freestanding-oil-filled-radiator-2000w/3730p"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        With .document

            Debug.Print .getElementById("collectionQuantity").Value

        End With

        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately both didn't work. I am after the value of value. -in the case above, 4.  Thanks again. IanG

Comment: What does doesn't work mean please? I put your HTML into a document and it worked fine. Can you supply the url for the webpage? Or more HTML ? For example, is there a parent iframe/frame ?

Comment: Actually, I thought it was erroring as the code within some error handling, but it's populating it with a blank. The url is https://www.screwfix.com/p/hd907-9q-freestanding-oil-filled-radiator-2000w/3730p and the value should read as "0" for you as you've not picked a local store. Thank you.

Comment: Is there a URL you can share?

Comment: in my comment above

Comment: I tried HTML.getElementsByTagName("p")(7).contentDocument.querySelector("#collectionQuantity").Value but that generates a run-time error 438.

Comment: I also tried using the class name HTML.getElementsByClassName("lg-24 md-12 cols")(3).contentDocument.querySelector("#collectionQuantity").Value but got the same error. :(

Comment: My selectors are correct. It just seems you have to ensure the local store is retained.

Comment: Absolutely stunning stuff!!!  Thank you.  You've saved the last bit of hair I have left.  Thank you.  Ian G.

Comment: How would one select a specific store using HTML instead of IE? Thanks. ianG